# Is there a way to stop my program from printing duplicates?

Tags: c, linked-list, combinations

I wrote this program, which is supposed to print all combinations whose sum is equal to a given number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "combinations.h"

int c = 0;

void findsubsets(unsigned int *numnumbers, int n, int i) {
    int j;
    if (i < 0)
        return;
    int sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i & (1 << j)) {
            sum = sum + numnumbers[j];
        }
    }
    if (sum == target) {
        c++;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i & (1 << j))
                printf("%u ", numnumbers[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    unsigned int iterations = pow(2, VECTOR_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations - 1 ; i++)
        findsubsets(numbers, VECTOR_SIZE, i);
    return 0;
}
```

```
//header file next

#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h

#define VECTOR_SIZE 6
unsigned int numbers[VECTOR_SIZE] = {1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1};
unsigned int target = 4;

#endif /* Header_h */
```

However, if as in the example in the header, a number is repeated in the given vector, then it prints out some combinations that include the same numbers. Is there a way to prevent it from doing so? I'm thinking maybe I should use linked lists (which would include all the valid combinations and then compare them, eliminate the ones that are equal, and print out the rest) but I'm pretty sure that would be very time-consuming to write and maybe not very efficient. Is there a less complicated way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: if you use a hash map, everytime you create a new one you can check if it is in the map, if not add it if it is move on.

Comment: never ever use `pow(2, VECTOR_SIZE);`. Use `1 << VECTOR_SIZE` intead which is hundreds of times faster. And what you're looking for is a [map/dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). In C++ there are already std::map and std::unordered_map but you'll have to implement it yourself in C

Comment: Or a hash set, which is a simplified hash map, instead of `A->B` it just stores the presence of `A`; make sure to include all the numbers in your hash code. Another way is to sort and lookup, but that has an asymptotically worse runtime.